# Keep div at top of window while content expands above it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
var divPos;

$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('open');
  $('div').not(this).addClass('close');
  divPos = $(this).offset().top;
});

$('button').click(function(){
 $('div').removeClass('open close');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: divPos
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
html, body {height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}

div {height:25%; transition:height 1s;}
div.open {height:400px;}
div.close {height:0;}

div:nth-of-type(1) {background:red;}
div:nth-of-type(2) {background:blue;}
div:nth-of-type(3) {background:green;}
div:nth-of-type(4) {background:yellow;}

button { margin-bottom:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<button>close</button>
```

I have a stack of divs and when the user clicks one it expands it's height, while the ones that weren't clicked get zero height. All heights are transitioned by css.

When a close button is clicked, all divs go back to the original size.

How can I have the window scroll position keep the previously opened div at the top of the screen while the divs above it are expanding?

I have tried getting the position of the clicked div at it's original state and using:

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: divPos
  }, 500);
```

Which basically works but it doesn't keep time with the css transition so it moves down before scrolling back up into position.

Here is a mockup of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0n6mxdt4/1/

The bounce back gets worse the lower the div it is.

Comment: What does `How can I have the window scroll position keep the previously opened div at the top of the screen while the divs above it are expanding?` mean??

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee In the example - click the yellow div. It expands. Now click the close button. It goes back to normal then scrolls the yellow div to the top of the window. I need that yellow div to remain perfectly at the top of the window while everything resizes.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, I think this is your answer. You need to add this line before animating to position:

```
$("html, body").scrollTop(divPos);
```

It is the working answer

```js
var divPos;

$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("open");
  $("div")
    .not(this)
    .addClass("close");
  divPos = $(this).offset().top;
  clickedPos = $(this);
});

$("button").click(function() {
  $("div").removeClass("open close");
  $("html, body").scrollTop(divPos);
  $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: divPos
    },
    1000
  );
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 25%;
  transition: height 1s;
}

div.open {
  height: 400px;
}

div.close {
  height: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: yellow;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<button>close</button>
```

Comment: No sorry. The top of the div needs to be at the top of the window during the whole close animation.

Comment: The problem is re-opening of yellow div while closing? Which starts from 0 to 25%? @user500665

Comment: Yes. I would need the `$("html, body").scrollTop(divPos);` to run constantly for the duration of the transition.

Comment: The problem is just yellow div, is not it? @user500665

Comment: It is all divs except the top one because it's top is always the same. The bounce back effect I mention in the question is worse the lower the div is in the stack.